# Use INDEX function with muliple criteria/MATCH functions in Excel

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I'm trying to create a front page report in excel and part of it needs a list of workers based on a couple dropdown menues.

I can create a list that only return unique value but I can't figure out how to limit the results to only names that have the correct office in a corresponding column.

My setup is like this.

A3 is a dropdown of office names, B3 is a dropdown of Months which are Worksheet titles.

On the other sheets column D contains the employee names, and column E are the offices they work in.

From A48 down on the cover sheet I want a list to generate of the workers that appear on the sheet specifed in B3, and have the correct office that is specified in A3.

This is what I have so far

```html
=INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&$B$3&"'!$D$2:$D$6000"),MATCH(0,COUNTIF($A$47:A47,INDIRECT("'"&$B$3&"'!$D$2:$D$6000")),0))
```

This works perfectly for creating a unique list from the other worksheet when pasted down from A48 on, but I can't figure out how to limit the list to show only the people that work in the correct office that's selected in A3

All knowledge I have of Excel in self taught thanks the forums like stackoverflow so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this formula in A48

`=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&$B$3&"'!D2:D6000"),MATCH(1,ISNA(MATCH(INDIRECT("'"&$B$3&"'!D2:D6000"),A$47:A47,0))*(INDIRECT("'"&$B$3&"'!E2:E6000")=$A$3),0)),"")`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copy down as far as required and further - when you run out of valid entries you get blanks